# Multidimensional array created from directory structure

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to put together a script to read a directory and create a multidimensional array with the same structure and contents as the structure on the file system.

In the past I just ran a script that traversed the directories and set the key as the full path and the values as the files found at that path. This time an array like that won't be as easy to work with.

I used that old script to get the file structure that I'm working with here:

```
Array
(
    [0] => files/example
    [1] => files/example/2015
    [2] => files/example/2015/Documents
    [3] => files/example/2015/Documents/Catalogs
    [4] => files/example/2015/Documents/Manuals
    [5] => files/example/2015/Documents/Press-Releases
    [6] => files/example/2015/Documents/Sell-Sheets
    [7] => files/example/2015/Email-Templates
    [8] => files/example/2015/Email-Templates/HTML-Templates
    [9] => files/example/2015/Email-Templates/Outlook-Templates
    [10] => files/example/2015/Email-Templates/Template-Image-Files
    [11] => files/example/2015/Images
    [12] => files/example/2015/Images/Ads-and-Flyers
    [13] => files/example/2015/Images/Catalog-and-PoP-Graphics
    [14] => files/example/2015/Images/Files-for-Web
    [15] => files/example/2015/Images/High-Resolution-Files
    [16] => files/example/2015/Images/Lifestyle-Shots
    [17] => files/example/2015/Images/Logos-and-Brand-Identity
    [18] => files/example/2015/Images/Product-Images
    [19] => files/example/2015/Images/Vector-Files
    [20] => files/example/2015/Other-Files
)
```

Ultimately there will be more folders under /files and multiple years inside each subfolder of /files.

In my searches I have found people presenting methods to convert a single path to a multidimensional array but I haven't been able to adapt any of those methods to my situation successfully. Some work partially, some don't work at all. The closest I've come to getting this to be the way I want is with this code:

```
function getfiles($path,&$files){
    if(($h = opendir($path))){
        $args = explode('/',$path);
        $folder = array_pop($args);
        if(!isset($files[$folder])) $files[$folder] = array();
        while(($file = readdir($h)) !== false){
            $check = $path . '/' . $file;

            // directory
            if(is_dir($check)){
                if(!in_array($file,array('.','..'))){
                    getfiles($check, $files[$folder]);
                }

            // file
            }else if(!is_dir($check)){
                $files[$folder][] = $file;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately that isn't quite right. It gives me this:

```
    Array(
    [example] => Array(
            [2015] => Array(
                    [Documents] => Array(
                            [Press-Releases] => Array()
                            [Sell-Sheets] => Array()
                            [Catalogs] => Array()
                            [Manuals] => Array()
                        )
                    [Images] => Array(
                            [Lifestyle-Shots] => Array()
                            [Files-for-Web] => Array()
                            [High-Resolution-Files] => Array()
                            [Product-Images] => Array()
                            [Catalog-and-PoP-Graphics] => Array()
                            [Ads-and-Flyers] => Array()
                            [Vector-Files] => Array()
                            [Logos-and-Brand-Identity] => Array()
                        )
                    [Other-Files] => Array()
                    [Email-Templates] => Array(
                            [Outlook-Templates] => Array()
                            [Template-Image-Files] => Array()
                            [HTML-Templates] => Array()
                        )
                )
        )

    [2015] => Array(
            [Documents] => Array(
                    [Press-Releases] => Array()
                    [Sell-Sheets] => Array()
                    [Catalogs] => Array()
                    [Manuals] => Array()
                )
            [Images] => Array(
                    [Lifestyle-Shots] => Array()
                    [Files-for-Web] => Array()
                    [High-Resolution-Files] => Array()
                    [Product-Images] => Array()
                    [Catalog-and-PoP-Graphics] => Array()
                    [Ads-and-Flyers] => Array()
                    [Vector-Files] => Array()
                    [Logos-and-Brand-Identity] => Array()
                )
            [Other-Files] => Array()
            [Email-Templates] => Array(
                    [Outlook-Templates] => Array()
                    [Template-Image-Files] => Array()
                    [HTML-Templates] => Array()
                )
        )
    [Documents] => Array(
            [Press-Releases] => Array()
            [Sell-Sheets] => Array()
            [Catalogs] => Array()
            [Manuals] => Array()
        )
    [Catalogs] => Array()
    [Manuals] => Array()
    [Press-Releases] => Array()
    [Sell-Sheets] => Array()
    [Email-Templates] => Array(
            [Outlook-Templates] => Array()
            [Template-Image-Files] => Array()
            [HTML-Templates] => Array()
        )
    [HTML-Templates] => Array()
    [Outlook-Templates] => Array()
    [Template-Image-Files] => Array()
    [Images] => Array(
            [Lifestyle-Shots] => Array()
            [Files-for-Web] => Array()
            [High-Resolution-Files] => Array()
            [Product-Images] => Array()
            [Catalog-and-PoP-Graphics] => Array()
            [Ads-and-Flyers] => Array()
            [Vector-Files] => Array()
            [Logos-and-Brand-Identity] => Array()
        )
    [Ads-and-Flyers] => Array()
    [Catalog-and-PoP-Graphics] => Array()
    [Files-for-Web] => Array()
    [High-Resolution-Files] => Array()
    [Lifestyle-Shots] => Array()
    [Logos-and-Brand-Identity] => Array()
    [Product-Images] => Array()
    [Vector-Files] => Array()
    [Other-Files] => Array()
)
```

As you can see, it creates a root array key for every folder instead of just stopping with the examples folder.

I'm sure there's a simple logic bug with my function that is causing this but either I'm too close to it to notice it or my brain just isn't cooperating with me anymore.

Or that's just not the right method to use for what I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, I'm an idiot. There's nothing wrong with my function, just the way I was using it.

I was looping through that first array I posted in my question to build my multidimensional array. That's why the last array I posted was full of every folder as a root array key.

Don't know what I was thinking. (Answer: I wasn't...)

Instead of:

```
$files = array()
$struct = traverse('files/example');
foreach($struct as $path){
    getfiles($path,$files);
}
```

All I needed to do was this:

```
$files = array();
getfiles('files/example',$files);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made it in a simple way using `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`, `RecursiveIteratorIterator` and `eval`

```
$rootpath = '.';
$fileinfos = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootpath));

$tree = array();

foreach($fileinfos as $pathname => $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        continue;
    }

    $arrayNotation = str_replace("/", "']['", str_replace(array('/.', '/..', '.'), '', $pathname));

    $str = <<<STRING
if (!isset(\$tree['$arrayNotation'])) {
    \$tree['$arrayNotation'] = array();
}
STRING;

    eval($str);
}

echo '<pre>', var_dump($tree);
```